# What does "engringué" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, poésie

The sentence is:

> les fauteuils de dentiste engringués les uns dans les autres.

Does anyone know what "engringué" mean? I get the image created by the writer here, but I couldn't find the word.

Is it a neologism? How was it created?

Answer (score 6):

[On dit](https://books.google.com/books?id=AnhcAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=engringuer) qu'il s'agit d'un verbe formé par substitution d'un suffixe antonyme appliqué à un verbe où il y a désuffixation (*Les verbes de Céline*, Alphonse G. Juilland) :

> [Dégringoler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9gringoler), dégringuer, [en](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en-)gringuer.

*Engringuer* signifierait dans ce cas *(s')[emmêler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/emm%C3%AAler), (s')[enchevêtrer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/enchev%C3%AAtrer)* ; selon le cas il peut aussi vouloir dire *séduire, embobiner*, par dérivation de [*faire la gringue*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_du_gringue) (*Les verbes de Céline*, Alphonse G. Juilland).